# SQL Server - Why would my SPID be "SUSPENDED" but not blocked, while creating an index?

Tags: sql-server, suspend

I have a SQL 2005 x64 server, and when I attempt to issue some queries against it (for example, when I try to create an index), my SPID goes to "sleeping" immediately, and seems to wait there indefinitely. It's not being blocked (the `BLKBY` column in `SP_WHO2` is empty), and the `CPU` and `DiskIO` values are very small (under 300 each), and not growing.

What could my query possibly be waiting for? If I do a `SELECT *` off the table I'm indexing, I get all million rows back within a minute or so, so it's not blocked table access, or even (it seems) table contention.

Any thoughts on other things I could check? Do I just need to give in and restart my SQL instance? :)

DETAILS: I'm running the `CREATE INDEX` from another tab in SSMS, and it's never returning - it just shows `Executing` and never returns, so I don't think the process has been abandoned.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
select * 
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
join sys.dm_os_tasks t on r.session_id = t.session_id
where r.session_id = <spid of create index>;
```

This will show not only the status of the request, but also all the tasks spawned by the request. An online `CREATE INDEX` may spawn parallel threads and will suspend itself until they're finish.

Comment: excellent answer.  just what I was looking for.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/ got me going, and this showed me exactly where the problem was.

Comment: And if only row is returned and its status is "suspended"?

Answer (score 4):

The `Suspended` state can sometimes be misleading. For example, your query could be `Suspended` while waiting for disk I/O to complete.  This can be verified by running the below query and checking the `wait_type` column. `PAGEIOLATCH_EX` indicates that the query is blocked due to waiting for disk I/O.  This doesn't mean that the query is not making progress.

See [this page](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/sql-server-pageiolatch_ex-wait-type/) for more information about `PAGEIOLATCH_EX`

And here is the query that returns the aforementioned information

```
 SELECT qs.percent_complete ,
        qs.session_id ,
        scheduler_id ,
        blocking_session_id ,
        qs.status ,
        command ,
        wait_time ,
        wait_type ,
        last_wait_type ,
        wait_resource ,
        ST.text ,
        host_name ,
        program_name
 FROM   sys.dm_exec_requests qs
        LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions es ON ( qs.session_id = es.session_id )
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS ST
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. It was indeed helpful in pin-pointing the command which is taking CPU time and IO.

Answer (score -2):

The command is completed and the connection is waiting for the next command.

http://blogs.msdn.com/psssql/archive/2008/04/21/how-it-works-what-is-a-sleeping-awaiting-command-session.aspx

From the URL:
"This issue is as old as SQL Server.  In fact, it goes back to Sybase days but continues to fool and puzzle administrators.

A session with that status of sleeping / awaiting command is simply a client connection with no active query to the SQL Server. The table below shows the transitions from running to sleeping states for a session."

Comment: But I'm running the command from SSMS, and my session still shows "Executing" - it doesn't appear to be done at all, and it went to "Suspended" way too fast to have actually completed. Interesting link, though - I was unaware of that connection.